# Smallest possible piece of code to automatically replace ampersands in XML Doc

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

For an XML document containing the escape characters, I have seen several options to work around. What is the fastest/smallest possible method to either ignore invalid characters or replace them with correct format?

The data is going into a database and the column that this data with the potential for funny characters is going into (location address) is the least important.

I'm getting the entity_name parsing error at the dataset.ReadXml command

Here is my code:

```
FN = Path.GetFileName(file1).ToString()
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(Path.Combine(My.Settings.Local_Meter_Path, FN), New XmlReaderSettings())
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the smallest code? Not the easiest to understand or most flexible or easiest to integrate?

Comment: Yeah, mostly because it will likely be a small/largely unused field of the data I'm working with. Im an intern :/  ...The address field of this data where people seem to be typing all kinds of funny characters and descriptions is unimportant compared to the Meter ID numbers and other things.

Comment: A very important point to learn is that small code is not necessarily good code. Good code is readable, and maintainable. Instead of asking for smallest solution, just ask for a solution. You can then refactor so that it's simple.

Comment: Careful what you ask for... http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/